# Entity Framework - Update many to many relationships

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4

I'm having a problem attempting to update a Many to Many type relationship in my table.

Here's my code:

```
            foreach (ThingCategory category in this.unit.Context.ThingCategories.Where(c => c.ThingId == thingId))
            {
                if (this.unit.Context.Entry(category).State == EntityState.Detached)
                {
                    this.unit.Context.ThingCategories.Attach(category);
                }

                this.unit.Context.ThingCategories.Remove(category);
            }

            foreach (ThingCategory category in categories)
            {
                if (this.unit.Context.Entry(category).State == EntityState.Detached)
                {
                    this.unit.Context.ThingCategories.Attach(category);
                    this.unit.Context.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                else
                {
                   this.unit.Context.Entry(category).CurrentValues.SetValues(category);
                   this.unit.Context.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }

            this.unit.Context.SaveChanges();
```

I'm getting:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.

The ThingCategory entity uses a composite primary key made from a ThingId and CategoryId.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to doing this the right way?

Thanks,